# How to format Milliseconds with Intl.DateTimeFormat API

Tags: javascript, localization

I need to format a Timestamp in a specific locale (not utc, not browser locale). But I must have the millisecond part of the date, too. My first attempt was `second:'numeric'` with the `DateTimeFormat` API:

```
new Intl.DateTimeFormat(
    'de-de', // german as an example, user selectable
    { 
        year: 'numeric', month: 'numeric',  day: 'numeric', 
        hour: 'numeric', minute: 'numeric', 
        second: 'numeric',
        hour12: false
    }
)
.format(new Date()); // Date as an example
```

But the result is something like `"26.11.2018, 09:31:04"` and not `"26.11.2018, 09:31:04,243"`.

Is there a easier possibility than using `formatToParts()` and detect the missing millisecond and add it again with the `Intl.NumberFormat`?

Attention: If someone needs to implement this, Microsoft browsers are adding Left-To-Right-Mark Unicode chars into the output. So you can not `parseInt` the result from `formatToParts()` without sanitizing.

Edit:
Moved the question to https://github.com/tc39/ecma402/issues/300

Comment: Yup, there doesn't seem to be a clean answer to this. Since seconds are completely immune from timezone issues, I would remove seconds from your formatting object, and concatenate them with a call to `myDate.getSeconds()`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is now spec'ed and implemented in Chrome and Firefox:

https://github.com/tc39/ecma402/issues/300

https://caniuse.com/mdn-javascript_builtins_intl_datetimeformat_datetimeformat_options_parameter_options_fractionalseconddigits_parameter

```js
new Date().toLocaleString('de-de', { year: 'numeric', month: 'numeric',  day: 'numeric', 
        hour: 'numeric', minute: 'numeric', 
        second: 'numeric',
        fractionalSecondDigits: 3
    }
)
// or
new Intl.DateTimeFormat(
    'de-de', // german as an example, user selectable
    { 
        year: 'numeric', month: 'numeric',  day: 'numeric', 
        hour: 'numeric', minute: 'numeric', 
        second: 'numeric', fractionalSecondDigits: 3,
        hour12: false
    }
)
.format(new Date());
// => "6.1.2021, 12:30:52,719"
```

Comment: Somehow I was always getting one more second when subtracting timestamp of two dates to get offset difference and then init new date based on that. After researching at many places, finally found this answer.